# what is function f(a,b) mean on below qustion?

Tags: c, function

the problem is from 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coolguy-and-two-subsequences

It said below.

```
    //f(a, b) is a function that returns the minimum element in interval [a, b]

ans = 0

for a -> [1, n]
    for b -> [a, n]
        for c -> [b + 1, n]
            for d -> [c, n]
                ans = ans + min(f(a, b), f(c, d))
```

I don't understand what function f(a,b) is.
for example f(1,1) is what value and why?
please, explain easy way.

Comment: The comment at the top doesn't help you?

Comment: @some programmer dude, Nope, It doesn't help me

Comment: Not that site again... We need some sort of official SO blacklist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a really strange description.

I think it should return the smallest array element (`A` being the array) for that range of indexes.

So basically:

```
static int f(const int *a, int low, int high)
{
  int smallest = INT_MAX;
  for(int i = low; i <= high; ++i)
    smallest = min(smallest, a[i - 1]);
  return smallest;
}
```

The `- 1` is since `a` is supposedly 1-indexed.

For the sample input `3 2 1`, we have `int a[] = { 3, 2, 1 };`, and thus `f(1, 1)` computes the minimum of just the first element, which is `3`.

Comment: unwind@,  I understand f(a, b) now, but what are c and d ?

Comment: @alexparkjw: `c` and `d` are just index values varying from `b+1` to `n` and `c` to `n` respectively.

Comment: I don't understand but i will give you green V. Thank you guys

Comment: I just looked at Hackerrank. The comment is totally misleading.

Comment: @chqrlie: I looked at the challenge, The time complexity of a brute force approach is **O(N^5)** which is rapidly exceeding the time limit for most test cases. Reducing the complexity by one or 2 orders of magnitude and even 3 for special cases is rather easy but insufficient and requires too much memory. This challenge is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The comment states this:
`f(a, b)` is a function that returns the minimum value of the element in the positions  `a and b` of the vector.

For example, `f(1,6)` looks in the vector for the `1st and 6th` elements and returns their minimum value. Notice for in the above pseudo-code you can have this: `f(10,2)`: which looks for the positions of `10 and 2` in the vector.

So what this code does is:

```
//f(a, b) is a function that returns the minimum element in interval [a, b]

    ans = 0  //creates an empty object to fill later in the loop

    for a -> [1, n]    //iterates for the values of a (1 to N)
        for b -> [a, n]   //then iterates for the values of b (a to N)
            for c -> [b + 1, n]   //iterates for the values of c (b+1 to N) 
                for d -> [c, n]   //iterate values of d (c to N)
                    ans = ans + min(f(a, b), f(c, d)) //store the answer by keep adding the results in each iteration. for each position combination.
```

Comment: No, the comment does not state that. The comment says the _interval_, not the positions.

Comment: the comment might not state that, but when i look at the examples in the website presented thats what i see and understand.

Comment: @HerculesApergis Don't you think it's funny that `[1, n]` from the first `for` means "1 to N", but for `f` the meaning of the values in brackets is completely different?

Comment: If I had the function `f` implied by the website given i would be more likely to understand. It is of course weird. But when i look at the examples of the website thats what i understand. :)

Comment: I do not undertstand your quesiton!